# Clickhouse DB slows down on a daily basis at 10am for seemingly no reason

Tags: database, performance, devops, clickhouse

I have been using Clickhouse at work for analytics purposes for a while now.

I am currently running Clickhouse v22.6.3 revision 54455 on-premise on a VM with:

- fast storage
- 200Gb of RAM
- no swap
- a 40-cores CPU.

I have a few Tb of data, but no table bigger than 300 Gb. I do not use distributed tables or replication yet, and I write frequently into Clickhouse (but I don't use deletes or updates and prefer using things like the ReplacingMergeTree engine). I also leverage the MaterializedView feature for a few tables. Let me know if you need any more context or parameter, I use a pretty standard configuration.

Now, for a few months I have been experiencing performances issues where the server significantly slows down every day at 10am, and I cannot figure out why.
Based on Clickhouse built-in Graphite monitoring, the "symptoms" of the issue seem to be as follow:

At 10am:

**On the server side:**

- Both load and RAM usage remain reasonable. Load goes up a little.
- Disk write await time goes up (which I suspect is what leads to higher load)
- Disk utilization % skyrockets to something between 90 and 100%

**On Clickhouse side:**

- `DiskSpaceReservedForMerge` stays roughly the same (ie between 0 and 70Gb)
- both `OpenFileForRead` and `OpenFileForWrite` go up by a factor of ~2
- `BackgroundCommonPoolTask` goes slightly up, so does `BackgroundSchedulePoolTask` (which I found weird, because I thought this pool was dedicated to distributed operations - which I don't use) - both numbers remain seemingly reasonable
- The number of active `Merge` tasks per minutes drop significantly but I'm unsure whether it's a consequence of slow writing or if it's causing it
- both insert and general querying time are multiplied by ~10 which renders the database effectively unusable even for small tasks

Restarting Clickhouse usually fixes the problem but I obviously do not want to restart my main database every day at 10am. Most of the heavy load I put on the DB (such as data extraction and transformation, etc) happens earlier in the morning (and end around 7-8am) and runs fine. **I do *not* have any heavy tasks running at 10am.** The Clickhouse VM takes most of its host resources and I have confirmed with the devOps team that there doesn't seem to be a problem on the host or anything else scheduled on it at that time.

---

Is there any kind of background tasks or process that is run by Clickhouse on a daily basis and that could have a high impact on our disk capacity? What else can I monitor to figure out what is causing this problem?

Again, let me know if I can be more thorough on our settings and the state of the DB when the "bug" occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use https://github.com/innogames/graphite-ch-optimizer ?

Do you use TTL ?

```sql
select * from system.merges;

select * from system.part_log where event_time between ~10am~
```

Comment: No we don't use the GraphiteMergeTree engine (or an like graphite-ch-optimizer optimizer) or TTL, except for Clickhouse system tables themselves.  
I've looked into system.part_log but it doesn't contain much more information than Clickhouse's graphite monitoring system